Printer LBP6030 in Debian 12
I am using Debian 12. I bought a Canon LBP6030 printer.
I installed the linux driver (linux-UFRIILT-drv-v500-uken-18.tar.gz) from their website.
lpinfo -v gave me usb://Canon/LBP6030/6040/6018L?serial=0000A1O25L4L.
So, I ran the following command to add the printer:
 sudo lpadmin -p LBP6030-6040-6018L -E -v "usb://Canon/LBP6030/6040/6018L?serial=0000A1O25L4L" -P /usr/share/ppd/CNRCUPSLBP6030ZNK.ppd

It says:
lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.
I went to http://localhost:631/printers/LBP6030-6040-6018L to print a test page.
It says: stopped "Filter failed"
I went to https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSFilter
Not sure where to go from here.
